# Radio Button panel toggle in Bootstrap Nav-tab not display correct content selection

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, toggle, panel, user-experience

Interesting problem that is just driving me crazy.  I am trying to have the radio button labeled "Banks" to display a hidden panel by default.
Here's the image:
[radio_button_default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYCRE.png)

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/3xL9yy2d/6/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Default 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab">Default 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">
          <!--NAV TAB CONTENT SELECTION-->
          <form name="ServiceSelection">
          <input type="radio" id="bankview" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="bank" checked="checked" />
          <label for="bankview">Banks</label> |
          <input type="radio" id="schoolview" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="school" />
          <label for="schoolview">Schools</label>
          </form>
          <!--NAV TAB CONTENT SELECTION-->
          <hr />
          <div id="bank" class="none">
            <!--BANK LISTINGS-->
            <div class="col-lg-12 clearfix">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 border-red">
                Left Bank List
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 border-blue">
                Right Bank List
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="school" class="none">
            <!--SCHOOL LISTINGS-->
            <div class="col-lg-12 clearfix">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 border-red">
                Left School List
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 border-blue">
                Right School List
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">Default 2 Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried removing the CSS class="none" from the `<div>` to have the panel be available on pageload, but that only caused more problems with the other radio button.

The experience I am looking for is the tab Default 1 to display the content of panel selected by the "Banks" radio button, with the option to toggle between bank and schools.

I would appreciate if anyone could help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change form name to form id and use the below js 
`var $radioold = $('input[name=thing]:checked');
    $('#NetVersion input').on('change', function() {
    var $radio = $('input[name=thing]:checked');
    var id = $radio.attr('id');
    var idold = $radioold.attr('id');
    $radioold = $radio;
    $('#' + id + 'View').show();
    $('#' + idold + 'View').hide();
});`

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z8735h3/16/)

Comment: That worked great, but I overlooked the fact that in the same jsfiddle, tab Default2 may also contain the same functionality, meaning there will be additional options to choose from.

Comment: I have added a new JSFiddle to exemply the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/9z8735h3/5/